# How to connect and run Redis commands on remote server?

Tags: bash, redis

We are running Redis on our enterprise cluster. I need to run Redis flush command to from my local edgenode. Is there a way I can connect to commands on remote Redis using bash scripts. Basically, we want to run Redis command from a remote server/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [redis-cli](https://redis.io/docs/manual/cli/)

You can specify your remote Redis server host and port

```
redis-cli -h your.remote.server -p 1234
```

Or even with commands

```
redis-cli -h your.remote.server -p 1234 SET KEY VALUE
```

You also need to enable Redis to accept connections for other machines than the one it is running. Please see [bind](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/51da5c3dde38b138c68733977e53eee789e51d10/redis.conf#L57) directive in redis.conf